# Is levelOfBreathing set correctly to where it is a private integer property

Tags: java

```
public class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

    private int levelOfBreathing = 21;
    public Animal(Integer levelOfBreathing) {
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the value passed into the constructor isn't being assigned to the field. The value of `levelOfBreathing` would remain 21.

Edit:

Edit the constructor of Animal to look like this.

```
public Animal(Integer levelOfBreathing) {
    this.levelOfBreathing = levelOfBreathing;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so. I think you will need to explicitly set it, as in,

```
  public Animal(int levelOfBreathing) {
     // constructor for the Animal class
     this.levelOfBreathing = levelOfBreathing;
  }
```

Comment: `self` isn't valid in Java, I think you meant `this`.

Comment: Should be "this" in Java. "self" is used in other language(s).

Comment: he had `self.levelOfBreathing = levelOfBreathing;` Python I assume

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want this for your parent class:

```
public class Animal {

    private int levelOfBreathing = 21;

    public Animal(Integer levelOfBreathing)   {
        this.levelOfBreathing = levelOfBreathing;
    }
}
```

It looks like you wrote `RuntimeException` instead of `Animal` for the constructor for some reason.

Note that `this.levelOfBreathing` is used to specify the field rather than the constructor parameter, since they have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. By specifying `levelOfBreathing` as a parameter into your constructor you are acknowledging that the value of `levelOfBreathing` will be coming from someone else.

change it to something like this, this will change `levelOfBreathing` to whatever you pass into the constructor

```
  public Animal(int levelOfBreathing) 
  {
     //the this keyword refers to an instance of Animal
     this.levelOfBreathing = levelOfBreathing;
  }
```

Comment: Did i set the levelOfBreathing correctly to where it defaults to 21? it has to be a private int.

Comment: Well you set it so it was initialized to 21 yes, but if you pass in another value for `levelOfBreathing` when you construct the animal object, that value will be overwritten